# What should I do if I find my own solution to my problem?

Tags: support, self-answer

I have a problem that many seems to have. I found a solution. However, another solution is more informative and I wouldn't be able to find my solution if not because of it.

[Wi-Fi not connecting](https://superuser.com/questions/991436/wi-fi-not-connecting)

This is the URL.

I think my own answer is useful too because people should try that before giving up. The other answer tells that my tplink is windows 10 compatible and is also very useful.

Now, what should I do on this situation? I just want the page to be useful to readers.

Comment: And what should I do about my own question?

Comment: My answer was deleted

Comment: If turning it on and off again was the answer, why didn't you select your own answer?

Comment: Because it seems to be too trivial. Also I am not really sure it's really what solves it. I did that before. Somehow after weeks of frustation doing it again work. It doesn't look like firm information worthy answer. Also I don't feel like depriving some good answer with good information in favor of mine.

Comment: I tried to tell you about it but there is no option for me to talk to any mod about it besides creating this thread.

Answer (score 5):

Click on the **Answer Your Question** button at the bottom and post an answer to your own question. Note that you generally cannot accept your own answer immediately; you can accept your own answers after 48 hours from the time you posted your question. This will ensure everyone can benefit from this information.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You absolutely should.

See [here](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Its also perfectly fine to pick another answer as the correct one, and add additional information - I did it with this question since [my own answer was slightly broader in scope](https://superuser.com/questions/458465/speeding-up-optimising-internet-access-for-a-slow-connection/459883#459883) but the answer I selected got me on that path.

Do note that folk expect the same quality they'd expect of an answer not written for your own question.